# Understanding Reference to an Object from within a Java Object Array

Tags: java, arrays, pointers, memory

I wrote some code to understand what would happen if I store a mixture of primitives, objects mutable or immutable into an Array object. Could I amend them after storage and see if it Dereferenced these things correctly and returned their amended values. I did not get what I had expected my code to do ? I think I know why and would like to clarify whether this understanding is correct. Here is the code.

```
public class DriverApp3 {

private static String CYEAR = "2014" ;
private static StringBuffer CYEARFLG = new StringBuffer("1914") ;

public double money = 2.13 ;

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Integer j = 12 ;
    DriverApp3 d = new DriverApp3(); 
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("Unicorn");
    MutableInteger mi = new MutableInteger(67);
    int i = 76 ;

    Object[] parseXML = new Object[]{j,DriverApp3.CYEAR,d, d.money,DriverApp3.CYEAR, sb, mi, DriverApp3.CYEARFLG,i};

    //                               0           1      2      3        4             5   6           7          8
    System.out.println("======chng of all original values ==========");
    j = 13 ; 
    d.money = 3.14 ; 
    parseXML[4]="2015";
    DriverApp3.CYEAR = "2013"; 
    mi.set(9);
    sb.replace(3,5,"KO");
    DriverApp3.CYEARFLG.replace(0,4,"1939");
    i = 7 ;

    Object[] chngdO = new Object[]{j,DriverApp3.CYEAR,d, d.money,DriverApp3.CYEAR, sb, mi, DriverApp3.CYEARFLG,i};

    int cnt = 0 ;
    for (Object m : parseXML)
    {
        Integer s_objid = m.hashCode();
        String clsType = "Type="+m.getClass().getTypeName();
        String clsName = "SimplName="+m.getClass().getSimpleName();
        String canName = "CanonName="+m.getClass().getCanonicalName();

        Object n = chngdO[cnt];
        Integer ns_objid = n.hashCode();
        String nclsType = "Type="+n.getClass().getTypeName();
        String nclsName = "SimplName="+n.getClass().getSimpleName();
        String ncanName = "CanonName="+n.getClass().getCanonicalName();


        System.out.println(cnt + ": Hashcode=" + s_objid + ":" + clsType + ":" + m + "\n " + ": Hashcode=" + ns_objid + ":" + nclsType /*+ ":"+ clsName+ ":"+  canName*/+ ":" + n + "\n" );
        cnt++ ;
    }

}

@Override
public String toString()
{

    return "Hashcode="+this.hashCode() + "," + DriverApp3.CYEAR  ;
}
```

}

The mutable class is also here .....

/**
 * 
 * @author code snippet from stackoverflow.com
 * Not thread safe
 */
public class MutableInteger {

```
private int value;
public MutableInteger(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
public void set(int value) {
    this.value = value;
}
public int intValue() {
    return value;
}

public String toString()
{
    return "id="+this.hashCode()+" val=" + this.value ; 
}
```

}

The output of my application is .....

```
======chng of all original values ==========
```

0: Hashcode=12:Type=java.lang.Integer:12
 : Hashcode=13:Type=java.lang.Integer:13

1: Hashcode=1537249:Type=java.lang.String:2014
 : Hashcode=1537248:Type=java.lang.String:2013

2: Hashcode=366712642:Type=xander.DirRefOrCopy.DriverApp3:Hashcode=366712642,2013
 : Hashcode=366712642:Type=xander.DirRefOrCopy.DriverApp3:Hashcode=366712642,2013

3: Hashcode=815979831:Type=java.lang.Double:2.13
 : Hashcode=300063655:Type=java.lang.Double:3.14

4: Hashcode=1537250:Type=java.lang.String:2015
 : Hashcode=1537248:Type=java.lang.String:2013

5: Hashcode=1829164700:Type=java.lang.StringBuffer:UniKOrn
 : Hashcode=1829164700:Type=java.lang.StringBuffer:UniKOrn

6: Hashcode=2018699554:Type=xander.DirRefOrCopy.MutableInteger:id=2018699554 val=9
 : Hashcode=2018699554:Type=xander.DirRefOrCopy.MutableInteger:id=2018699554 val=9

7: Hashcode=1311053135:Type=java.lang.StringBuffer:1939
 : Hashcode=1311053135:Type=java.lang.StringBuffer:1939

8: Hashcode=76:Type=java.lang.Integer:76
 : Hashcode=7:Type=java.lang.Integer:7

Answer (score 0):

Index 0
For the Integer j, it is immutable, so as soon as I amend it outside the array the 0th one is still pointing to the one with value 12 since it is still alive on wherever Java keeps it's immutable single copy for that Integer. This is apparently an area where all runtime constants for each class or interface is kept. In this case it is the String literal area. The amended j is pointing to a new Immutable single copy of value 13. See Hashcodes differ as well.

Index 1
Same issue like above. Just because it is a member of DriverApp3 you would have expected to have amended itself but it does not because the array has stored an old value of the memory address String in wherever java stores the single copy of that immutable. Since, that address is still "alive" it keeps pointing to that memory address within the array. Very very unintuitive - not sure whether there are other patterns or languages that handle this better. It could be a source of error. Want to make sure you reflect your changes then - use MUTABLE objs within it instead of IMMUTABLE. Or, you have the additional thinking overhead of having to remember that Java might Autobox your primitive (if you were storing a primitive ) into an Object literal depending on whether it is a String, Integer, Double etc.

Index 2
Everything works as expected - it is pointing to the array. So, it continues to point to the same mutable object address when it was changed.

Index 3
Again the double gets Autoboxed into a immutable Double. So, it is the same issue like String and Integer because it is an Object Array. Surely, been like this since Java 1 - btw - I am using Java 8 compiler here.

Index 4
parseXML[4]="2015";
Well here we are directly overwriting the address with the address of the immutable String literal 2015

Index 5 & 6
StringBuffer and MutableInteger reflect amendments correctly because they still point to the same address. Java does not create a new copy because they are meant to mutable by the very nature of they have been defined.

Index 7
Reflects the changes because it is a mutable StringBuffer and not a shared immutable literal !!

Index 8
Suffers from the same issue of a primitive being autoboxed into a immutable shared single copy literal.

So, if you want the contents of your stored Array to reflect your amended changes outside of the array use Mutable Objects. And, beware of the trap of automatic Autoboxing into immutable Object literals.